# How to use MapQuest in Salesforce

Tags: apex

I need to use `mapquest Directions Web Service` to calculate distance between `two USA zipcodes`.Get the distance between `Account(Only One) and all the Contacts(List)`.

I have a Account with GeoLocation field type.and I have list of Contacts and am saving (Latitude,Longitude) in GeoLocation type.

The problem is how to send `Account Latitude and longitude` and `Contact Latitude and Longitude` to MapQuest to get the distance in miles.

I read mapquest documentaction but i would not get how to do this.The problem i am facing is how to Call mapquest api through apex controller and get distance values back to controller.please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far.  If you have not attempted anything yet, it seems like you are asking us to write the code for you.  Consultants get paid good money to write these integrations.  More than happy to help if you are stuck, but not willing to write code for you.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja Thanks for your solution.Am not asking to write code,the problem is how to send Account Latitude and longitude and Contact Latitude and Longitude to MapQuest to get the distance in miles

Comment: Can you provide the code you have and a link to the mapquest API and webservices

Comment: I am asking that question here,How to call the mapquest API and webservices in Apex Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does MapQuest have an API for what you are trying to achieve?

Assuming it does, and that the API resembles these [Geocoding ones](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/), your Apex code needs to make a web service call (without the complication of SOAP/WSDL) supplying the correct GET parameters and needs to parse the JSON response to get the result.

There is a basic example of how to make a GET request in the [HttpRequest Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) documentation and the [JSON](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm) class is available for parsing the response. You can Google and find many more articles and guides. You'll only need about 50 lines of Apex to do this.

Note that as many services include JavaScript APIs it can sometimes be simpler to do the work in the client (the browser) rather than the server (Salesforce), but that is only a possibility if it fits into how you want your application to work.